# SSRS 2008 month number not displayed in order

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 report that generated columns of the months along with other data based on year halves.  I have the tablix column group and sort set for [Mon] and the first half of the year generated just fine but when I run the report for the second half it does not display in order :

```
MonthNumber 10       11        12        7     8       9
MonthName   October  Movember  December  July  August  September
```

The SQL code that is used generated the following rows which appear in order of month number.

```
Mon
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Comment: Looking at that, I wonder if `Mon` (which I presume is the month number) is coming through and/or being treated as text... You can see they are being sorted as strings, i.e. 10 will be before 7. Sorting by `=CInt(Fields!Mon.Value)`, i.e. explicitly sorting as an integer, would likely solve the issue. Can you confirm the data type of `Mon`?

Comment: Ian, your suggestion worked perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for the update - I figured that was 99% likely to be the issue, but difficult to confirm without replicating myself. Since it looks OK now, I'll add the suggestion as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that `Mon` is being treated as a string value, for whatever reason, i.e. from the query or in the dataset definition, as you can see that in your example the columns are being sorted as strings, i.e. 10 will be before 7 when sorted as text and not numeric values.

You have two options:

First is to sort by an expression like: `=CInt(Fields!Mon.Value)`, i.e. explicitly sorting as an integer, which solve the issue if `Mon` is being treated as text.

The other option is to make sure that `Mon` is being treated as an integer at the dataset level - either way should be fine.